# Mysql errno 150. I do not understand what is missing

Tags: mysql

The provinces table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shmarket`.`PROVINCES` (
`provinceId` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`provinceId`))
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The cities table

---

```
Table `shmarket`.`CITIES`
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shmarket`.`CITIES` (
`cityId` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`PROVINCES_provinceId` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`cityId`),
 INDEX `fk_CITIES_PROVINCES1_idx` (`PROVINCES_provinceId` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_CITIES_PROVINCES1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`PROVINCES_provinceId`)
 REFERENCES `shmarket`.`PROVINCES` (`provinceId`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


-----------------------------------------------------
Table `shmarket`.`USERS`
-----------------------------------------------------
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `shmarket`.`USERS` (
 `userId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `surname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 `registryDate` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`role` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
`CITIES_cityId` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
 UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),
 INDEX `fk_USERS_CITIES1_idx` (`CITIES_cityId` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_USERS_CITIES1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`CITIES_cityId`)
 REFERENCES `shmarket`.`CITIES` (`cityId`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When i create the users table mysql shows errno 150. I checked the code few times but its not working. I generated this code with mysql workbench and also is failing.

Comment: #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Where i not cant add foregin key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the InnoDB engine, the ON DELETE SET DEFAULT is your problem. Here's an excerpt from the manual:

While SET DEFAULT is allowed by the MySQL Server, it is rejected as invalid by InnoDB. CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements using this clause are not allowed for InnoDB tables.

You can use ON DELETE CASCADE or ON DELETE SET NULL, but not ON DELETE SET DEFAULT. There's more information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

This error also occurs if you are relating columns of different types, eg. int in the source table and BigInt in the destination table.

You can run

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```